# What are some interesting phrases which suggest that you are extremely busy?

Tags: phrases

If I want to say

> **I’m extremely busy**, I have no time, since I have my exams next month.

What are some interesting replacements for the bold text, both colloquial and written?

e.g. I am busy as a bee

Comment: Heard about Roget?

Comment: Please do not ask open ended, list questions.

Comment: This is not constructive and we could carry on for quite some time providing interesting phrases. We need either more context for the usage of the phrase or a better sense of what types of interesting phrases are desired (work appropriate, animal-referencing, in the form of similes). For these reasons, I vote to close.

Comment: Sorry, @user494461, despite my fellow EL&U members short-to- downright-discurteous comments, your question should be fine-tuned to fit the guidelines.  I hope you stick around, this site is educational and (usually) welcoming! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm slammed, I'm so busy I can't breathe, I'm so busy I can't remember my own name, I'm inundated, I'm buried, I'm overwhelmed, I'm just trying to keep my head above water, I'm so far behind I'll never catch up, I'm up to my ears, I've got too much on my plate.

Answer (score 3):

***"I'm so busy I don't know if I'm coming or going!"***

Or

***"I'm busier than a one-armed paper hanger!"***